# Convert code from VB into C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have problem to convert this VB code into C#

```
Public Event SendNewBid As EventHandler(Of BidEventInfo)
```

BidEventInfo is a name of class

C# code:

```
Public event SendNewBid ....??????
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public event EventHandler<BidEventInfo> SendNewBid;
```

for future conversions, you could use [this online](http://converter.telerik.com/) converter

Answer (score 2):

```
public event EventHandler<BidEventInfo> SendNewBid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public event EventHandler<BidEventInfo> SendNewBid;
```

You can use online [conversion tools](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).

Answer (score 0):

`public event EventHandler<BidEventInfo> SendNewBid;`

[here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) is a nice web utility if you need to convert your VB.Net code into C#